# Sum max of columns based on condition in excel

Tags: excel

So I have a large database that is structured like this:

```
   A        B          C         D    
Year,Month  Sales1     Sales 2    Sales 3
2013,Jan    100        220        50
2013,Feb    800         70       100
2013,Mar    200        300        10
```

etc, until 2016.

What I want is to sum the max of columns B,C and D when in 2013, 2014, etc.
In this case the answer should be: 800 + 300 +100.

In other words, I want excel to first check if the year is 2013, then do the max of all the individual columns for that year, and then sum those max together.

Currently I'm using MAX(IF(A:A=2013,C:C+D:D+E:E+F:F+G:G+H:H+J:J+K:K+L:L)) but it's not doing the trick. Any ideas?

Comment: Your formula gives  MAX(IF(A:A=2013... but from your table it would seem that column A does not contain years only, but rather Year,Month. Can you clarify?

Comment: I split the year into a new column, so I use the column with only the year value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{=MAX(IF(YEAR(A:A)=2013,B:B))+MAX(IF(YEAR(A:A)=2013,C:C))+MAX(IF(YEAR(A:A)=2013,D:D))+MAX(IF(YEAR(A:A)=2013,E:E))+MAX(IF(YEAR(A:A)=2013,F:F))+MAX(IF(YEAR(A:A)=2013,G:G))}`

you need a separate max(if()) for every column, and it all needs to be made into an array formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-Enter</kbd>

you also need to either input `YEAR(A:A)` as I did here, or make sure your A column only has values (not dates) such as 2013. This is because, as XOR LX mentioned, the date format is not the same as 2013. For example 1/1/2013 is 41275

Comment: Using entire column references within an array formula is not at all a good idea. Your formula is being forced to calculate over 12 million cells, an astonishing amount for a single formula.

Comment: If speed is an issue, then the range should be specified i.e `A1:A1000` instead of `A:A`

Comment: The benefit of array formulas is having smaller file sizes as a result of using a single formula instead of a different one for each row

Comment: The problem is that this database in all likelihood will grow much larger. So I don't want to keep on entering end row numbers. I could probably just pass the last valid row to address that though.

Comment: In that case, you'd best use a [dynamic range](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/830287)